# Deserializing a nested object in JSON to a specific type

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a class on the C# end that looks something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public SomeEnum FooType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public FooBase MyFoo { get; set; }
}
```

Where, basically, the value in the property `FooType` should tell you what specific type derived from `FooBase` is present in the property `MyFoo`.

Now if I just wanted to deserialize a object derived from `FooBase` I could just do something like:

```
var myFoo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonString, typeof(FooDerived)) as FooDerived;
```

But how do I deserialize a `MyObject` where the `FooBase` object is nested and the information about what type it is can only be determined by partially deserializing the object first?

I'm thinking this is going to need a custom converter derived from JsonConverter, but I'm not entirely sure how to make `ReadJson` work here.

Something like this?

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var result = new MyObject();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
        {
           var prop = reader.Value as string;
           if (prop == "FooType")
           {
               reader.Read();
               result.FooType = (SomeEnum)reader.ReadAsInt32();   // or something like that
           }
           if (prop == "MyFoo")
           {
               reader.Read();
               // now the reader.TokenType should be StartObject, but I can't
               // deserialize the object because I don't know what type it is
               // I might not have read "FooType" yet 
               // So I really need to pull this whole sub object out as a string
               // and deserialize it later???
           }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net)

Comment: @BrianRogers: I don't think it's an exact duplicate (the polymorphic part here is nested which makes this a little trickier), but I think the answer there does give me a really good lead on solving the problem. If I had found that question first when searching, I probably wouldn't have needed to ask.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought too-- it was close enough to allow you to solve the problem.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this answer as inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308474/1250301

I came up with something like this:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
    var foo = jObj["MyFoo"];
    var result = new MyObject(); 
    result.FooType = jObj["FooType"].ToObject<SomeEnum>();
    switch (result.FooType)
    {
        case SomeEnum.Value1:
            result.MyFoo = foo.ToObject<FooType1>();
            break;
        case SomeEnum.Value2:
            result.MyFoo = foo.ToObject<FooType2>();
            break;
        case SomeEnum.Value3:
            result.MyFoo = foo.ToObject<FooType3>();
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Unknown FooType");
    }
    return result;
}
```

The only problem here is that if I add new properties to the parent object, I'm going to need to manually map them. I thought I might be able to just do something like:

```
var parent = jObj.ToObject<MyObject>();
```

And then fill in the `MyFoo` object, but this will just end up calling `ReadJson` again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use `Json.Linq` to accomplish this. I am not in front of a computer to test this but I believe its something like:

```
string fooTypeJson = JObject.Parse(myJsonString).SelectToken("FooType").ToString();
FooType fooType = reader.DeserializeObject<FooType>(fooTypeJson);
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't quite figure out how to get hold of the original string once you are in `ReadJson`. I could try to handle it outside of the `JsonConverter`, but that seems like the wrong way to handle it.

Comment: Oh you've already deserialized it into the parent object it looks like. so why don't you just call it from the parent object? `FooType fooType = myFoo.FooType`?